# Concatenate a string and a counter

Tags: matlab

Im trying to concatenate a string and a counter in a loop. I have read like sprintf, str2number, and some stuff like that but still get stucked. Here is my code:

```
img1 = imread('t0.tif');
img2 = imread('t1.tif');
img3 = imread('t17.tif');
img4 = imread('t16.tif');
img5 = imread('t19.tif');
img6 = imread('t54.tif');
img7 = imread('t51.tif');
img8 = imread('t24.tif');
img9 = imread('t2.tif');
img10 = imread('t3.tif');
img11 = imread('t49.tif');

for i=1:10
   somevar{i} = rgb2gray(img{i});
   imshow(somevar{i});
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use different variable names, use a cell array of filenames like:

```
files = {
    't0.tif',
    't1.tif',
    't17.tif',
    't16.tif',
    't19.tif',
    't54.tif',
    't51.tif',
    't24.tif',
    't2.tif',
    't3.tif',
    't49.tif'
};

for i = 1:numel(files)
    img = imread(files{i});
    % ...
end
```